# COMException: "Object hasn't been initialized and can't be used yet"

Tags: c#, asp.net, modi

I am using Document imaging library for parsing text from image. My code is working fine on local but facing problem while deploying in windows server 2003.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Probably he is refering to [MODI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Document_Imaging), as he writes in the title.

Comment: I think you need to provide more info, e.g. the offending part of the code.

Comment: You obviously haven't initialized that object, just as the error says.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure MODI is installed(it will be there in MS Office Tools if installed).If not go through the link and install(http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-open-mdi-microsoft-document-imaging-format-with-office-2007/).if Still you r getting same error then try this

1)Go to IIS->ApplicatioPools->Default Applicationpool->Identity->custom account->Give the user name and password.